# JavaScript to handle unsigned int

Tags: javascript, c

I have a few functions to do data conversion (setbitu, setbits and set38bits), and convert to JS (setbitu, setbits, and set38bits), the answer did not come out the same. Can anyone point me out where I am do wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

```
void setbitu(unsigned char *buff, int pos, int len, unsigned int data)
{

    unsigned int mask=1u<<(len-1);
    int i;
    if (len<=0||32<len) return;
    for (i=pos;i<pos+len;i++,mask>>=1) {
        if (data&mask) 
            buff[i/8]|=1u<<(7-i%8); 
        else 
            buff[i/8]&=~(1u<<(7-i%8));
    }

}

void setbits(unsigned char *buff, int pos, int len, int data)
{

    if (data<0) 
    data|=1<<(len-1); 
    else 
        data&=~(1<<(len-1)); /* set sign bit */
    setbitu(buff,pos,len,(unsigned int)data);

}

/* set signed 38 bit field ---------------------------------------------------*/
void set38bits(unsigned char *buff, int pos, double value)
{

    int word_h=(int)floor(value/64.0);
    unsigned int word_l=(unsigned int)(value-word_h*64.0);
    setbits(buff,pos  ,32,word_h);
    setbitu(buff,pos+32,6,word_l);

}
```

I converted to JS function as follows:

```
/* set signed 38 bit field  ---------------------------------------------------*/
function set38bits(buff, pos, value)
{
    var word_l = new Uint32Array(1);
    var word_h=Math.floor(value/64.0);
    word_l[0]=(value-word_h*64.0);
    buff = setbits(buff,pos  ,32,word_h);
    buff = setbitu(buff,pos+32,6,word_l);
    return buff;

}
function setbitu(buff, pos, len, data)
{
    var mask=1<<(len-1);
    var i = 0;
    if (len<=0||32<len) return buff;
    for (i=pos;i<pos+len;i++,mask>>=1) {
        var loc = Math.floor(i/8);
        if (data&mask) {
            buff[loc]|=1<(7-i%8); 
        } else { 
            buff[loc]&=~(1<<(7-i%8));
        }
    }
    return buff;
}
function setbits(buff, pos, len, data)
{
    if (data<0) {
        data|=1<<(len-1); 
    } else {
        data&=~(1<<(len-1)); /* set sign bit */
    }
    return setbitu(buff,pos,len, data);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the results were and what results you are expecting from each function

Comment: The key issue is about the function setbits and setbitu, how to set the unsigned int declare and casting. I can not make it work.

Comment: You should provide an [mcve], including a complete running program in C with all data needed to exhibit the problem, including ovserved results and expected results, and the same in Java.